# Functional update - multivariable function with dynamic columns

Tags: kdb

Any help with the following would be much appreciated!

I have two tables: `table1` is a summary table whilst `table2` is a list of all data points. I want to be able to summarise the information in `table2` for each row in `table1`.

```
table1:flip `grp`constraint!(`a`b`c`d; 10 10 20 20);
table2:flip `grp`cat`constraint`val!(`a`a`a`a`a`b`b`b;`cl1`cl1`cl1`cl2`cl2`cl2`cl2`cl1; 10 10 10 10 10 10 20 10; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8);

function:{[grpL;constraintL;catL] first exec total: sum val from table2 where constraint=constraintL, grp=grpL,cat=catL};

update cl1:function'[grp;constraint;`cl1], cl2:function'[grp;constraint;`cl2] from table1;
```

The fourth line of this code achieves what I want for the two categories:`cl1` and `cl2`

In `table1` I want to name a new column with the name of the category (`cl1`, `cl2`, etc.) and I want the values in that column to be the output from running the function over that column.

However, I have hundreds of different categories, so don't want to have to list them out manually as in the fourth line. How would I pass in a list of categories, e.g. below?

```
`cl1`cl2`cl3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different methods you can look into.
The easiest method would be a functional update - http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/queries_q_sql#Functional_update

Below, though, should somewhat prove more useful, quicker and neater:

Your problem can be split into 2 parts. For the first part, you are looking to create a sum of each category by grp and constraint within table2. As for the second part, you are looking to join these results (the lookups) onto the corresponding records from table1.

You can create the necessary groups using `by`

```
q)exec val,cat by grp,constraint from table2
grp constraint| val       cat
--------------| ------------------------------
a   10        | 1 2 3 4 5 `cl1`cl1`cl1`cl2`cl2
b   10        | 6 8       `cl2`cl1
b   20        | ,7        ,`cl2
```

Note though, this will only create nested lists of the columns in your select query

Next is to `sum each` of the `cat` groups

```
q)exec sum each val group cat by grp,constraint from table2
grp constraint|
--------------| ------------
a   10        | `cl1`cl2!6 9
b   10        | `cl2`cl1!6 8
b   20        | (,`cl2)!,7
```

Then, to create the cat's columns you can use a pivot like syntax - http://code.kx.com/wiki/Pivot

```
q)cats:asc exec distinct cat from table2
q)exec cats#sum each val group cat by grp,constraint from table2
grp constraint| cl1 cl2
--------------| -------
a   10        | 6   9
b   10        | 8   6
b   20        |     7
```

Now you can use this lookup table and index into each row from table1

```
q)(exec cats#sum each val group cat by grp,constraint from table2)[table1]
cl1 cl2
-------
6   9
8   6
```

To fill the nulls with zeros, use the carat symbol - http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Caret

```
q)0^(exec cats#sum each val group cat by grp,constraint from table2)[table1]
cl1 cl2
-------
6   9
8   6
0   0
0   0
```

And now you can join on each row from table1 to your results using `join-each`

```
q)table1,'0^(exec cats#sum each val group cat by grp,constraint from table2)[table1]
grp constraint cl1 cl2
----------------------
a   10         6   9
b   10         8   6
c   20         0   0
d   20         0   0
```

HTH, Sean

Answer (score 5):

Sticking to your approach, you would just have to make your update statement functional and then iterate over the columns like so:

```
{![`table1;();0b;(1#x)!enlist ((';function);`grp;`constraint;1#x)]} each `cl1`cl2
```

Assuming you can amend table1 in place. If you must retain the original table1 then you can pass it by value though it will consume more memory

```
{![x;();0b;(1#y)!enlist ((';function);`grp;`constraint;1#y)]}/[table1;`cl1`cl2]
```

Another approach would be to aggregate, pivot and join though it's not necessarily a better solution as you get nulls rather than zeros

```
a:select sum val by cat,grp,constraint from table2
p:exec (exec distinct cat from a)#cat!val by grp,constraint from a
table1 lj p
```

Answer (score -1):

This approach is the easiest way to pass in a list of categories

```
{table1^flip x!function'[table1`grp;table1`constraint;]each x}`cl1`cl2
```